# Ionic 4 navigate to tabs

Tags: ionic4, ionic-tabs

I'm working on an Ionic 4 project, I've generated a tabs project.

What I want to do is create a Login page which is the default page.

When a user has signed in successfully I want to navigate to the tabs.

When I'm trying to do this I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'tabs'
```

These are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'Login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
```

In my Login Page I have a button as follows:

```
<ion-button expand="block" [href]="'tabs'" color="light" fill="outline">Sign in</ion-button>
```

When I generate a different page I am able to navigate to this page using the same way.

Comment: can you try using angular router? it would be something like this: <ion-button routerLink="/login"> Sign in </ion-button>

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Tried, but same error. The navigation also has to happen in the typescript. Validate the input, do a request and so on. But it says that it can't find the route...

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the same issue. I found a solution [here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16554). You need to add an additional route to your routes array.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'Login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginPageModule' },
  { path: 'tabs', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Add an additional route to tabs page in your app-routing.module.ts

```
{ path: 'app', loadChildren: './pages/tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' }
```

Step 2 : Add the tabs route inside the tabs-routing.module.ts

```
 const routes: Routes =[
   {
     path:'tabs',
     component:TabsPage,
     children:[
       {
         path : 'home',
         outlet : 'home',
         component : HomePage
       },
       {
         path : 'me',
         outlet : 'me',
         component : MePage
       }
     ]
   }
 ];
```

Step 3 : Link to the tabs page

```
 <ion-button href="app/tabs/(home:home)" routerDirection='root'>Tabs</ion-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. My first page is 'Sign In' page by default. I wanted to navigate to tabs module after button click.

`app-routing.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
   { path: 'app', loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule' },
   { path: '', loadChildren: './sign-in/sign-in.module#SignInPageModule' },
  { path: 'search', loadChildren: './search/search.module#SearchPageModule' }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

`tabs.router.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'home',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'my-requests',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../my-requests/my-requests.module#MyRequestPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'add-request',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../add-request/add-request.module#AddRequestPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'search',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../search/search.module#SearchPageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'profile',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfilePageModule'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/home',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule {}
```

`sign-in.module.ts`:

....

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: SignInPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [SignInPage]
})
```

....

`sign-in.page.html`:

```
 <ion-button (click)="navigateToProfile()">Sign In</ion-button>
```

`sign-in.page.ts`:

```
navigateToProfile(){
  this.navController.navigateRoot(`app/tabs/home`);
  }
```

Overall, my solution was:

- adding one more path: 'app' in my root module app-routing.module
- navigating to root with route with NavController. See [here](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-routing-navigation/) for more details, I found it here.